# API: SenderProfile Object - What is the DataType "TriggeredSendDefinition"?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, wsproxy

Documentation Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/senderprofile.htm

If you look at the above documentation link, '**AutoForwardTriggeredSend**' and '**AutoReplyTriggeredSend**' are both of DataType = "TriggeredSendDefinition". What is this?

For context, I would like to create some Sender Profiles via the SOAP api (utilising WS Proxy) that use custom RMM settings in order to select pre-created triggered sends and populate these fields in the Sender Profile RMM Setup:

- Triggered send to forward: _________
- Triggered send to auto reply with: _________

```
Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");
var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var profile = {
    Name: "test_001",
    CustomerKey: "test_001",
    Description: "test_001",

    FromName: "From_Name",
    FromAddress: "newsletter@test.test.com",
    
    UseDefaultRMMRulesSpecified: true,
    UseDefaultRMMRules: false,
    DirectForward: false,
    
    AutoForwardToName: "Test Support",
    AutoForwardToEmailAddress: "support@test.zendesk.com",

    AutoForwardTriggeredSend: ?????,

    AutoReply: true,
    AutoReplyTriggeredSend: ????
}
var request = api.createItem("SenderProfile", profile);
var response =request.Results;
Write(Stringify(request));
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggeredsenddefinition.htm

Comment: Try creating a triggered send, under Interactions>Triggered Email and then pass the external key in the script?

Comment: @SwatiMishra I've tried the triggered send's 'externalKey' and 'Name', but without luck.

Comment: Are the triggered Sends Activated/Running?

Comment: @SwatiMishra Yeah, the TSDs created for the RMM purposes are created and running all as expected.

Comment: May be create a sender profile manually with these settings, and then retrieve it using SOAP and see what do you get for those fields?

Comment: Good thinking, I've done that =D. However, AutoForwardTriggeredSend and AutoReplyTriggeredSend are not retrievable from the Object.

Comment: `{"Status":"Error: The Request Property(s) AutoForwardTriggeredSend,AutoReplyTriggeredSend do not match with the fields of SenderProfile retrieve","RequestID":"789514d7-2c5a-47c9-9ea6-b17430191dbd","Results":null,"HasMoreRows":false}`

Comment: Have you tried the GUID value of the TSD?

Comment: Hello @EazyE I'm not quite sure where to get that from. Any ideas? I will test that next!

Comment: Do a retrieve on the triggeredsend object

Comment: I did a retrieve of ObjectID from TriggeredSendDefinition object and tried that in my code SenderProfile WSProxy code above:  I did  `AutoForwardTriggeredSend: "3ae21282-adf0-aa11-a2f0-1402ec852b25"` and cloudpages just stalls, continuously loading, no success